# Include roles in User.login() and User.getCurrent() Angular SDK

Tags: angularjs, loopbackjs

I'm currently writing an administrative interface using the Loopback Angular SDK. After having dug through the documentation and code, I'm still no wiser as to how to include the user's roles in the response. It's causing me real headaches on the frontend because I'm not yet experienced enough with Angular to figure out how to enforce a role check on each of my states (I'm using UI-Router).

client: /auth.js

```
        // Log the user in
        $scope.doAuth = function() {

            $scope.hasError = false;
            $scope.busy = true;

            $scope.loginResult = User.login({include: 'roles'}, $scope.credentials,

                function wasSuccessfulAuth(authResponse) {

                    $scope.busy = true;

                    $rootScope.isAuthenticated = true;
                    $rootScope.user = authResponse.user;

                    $location.path('dashboard');

                },

                function wasFailedAuth(authResponse) {

                    $timeout(function() {

                        $scope.hasError = true;
                        $scope.authError = authResponse.data.error.message || 'Unknown error';
                        $scope.busy = false;

                    }, 1000);

                }

            )
        }
```

server: /common/models/user.json

```
{
  "name": "user",
  "plural": "Users",
  "base": "User",
  "properties": {

  },
  "relations": {
    "roles": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "RoleMapping",
      "foreignKey": "principalId"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": []
}
```

So this works in the API explorer, I have the routes I'd expect with an object that has a relation, but I can't seem to get any further than that... All that gets returned is the standard user login stuff (id, accessToken, email, etc) The docs seem to run cold when I get this far but I'd have thought this would have been a common use case?

This is a bit of a showstopper for me.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`User.login` returns AccessToken instance. To get user role, you should make separate request to fetch user, including role.

Comment: The explorer endpoint suggests an `include` parameter? Can this not be utilised to include RoleMappings?

Comment: No, only possible value for `User.login` `include` is `user`. But try this case http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Querying+related+models - section 'Using filters parameters with included relations', may be it helps to include `roles` to response.

Answer (score 6):

It's actually surprisingly easy to solve this problem using LoopBack: this is where "[model scopes](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Model+definition+JSON+file#ModeldefinitionJSONfile-Scopes)" come in very handy -- including the default scope which I find extremely useful for this type of situation.

First, a brief explanation of model scopes:

A model scope is like a saved query or "view", that allows you to specify a built-in `filter` for any query for that scope.  For example, if you set the default scope to a valid filter, every single query (of any kind) against your model will have this filter applied!

This can get you in a heap of trouble, but there's one use-case that's pretty safe (all other things equal) and actually addresses your question perfectly: when I said a scope lets you give a valid `filter`, it turns out filters aren't just `where` clauses, but also `include`, `limit`, etc.

So to solve your problem, you simply need a default scope on your `User` model that `include`s whatever you need to include.  For your example:

Simply add a **`scope`** object to your common/models/user.json:

```
{
  "name": "user",
  "plural": "Users",
  "base": "User",
  "scope": {
    "include": [
      "roles"
    ]
  },
  "properties": {

  },
  "relations": {
    "roles": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "RoleMapping",
      "foreignKey": "principalId"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": []
}
```

By adding a default scope with an "include", LoopBack will automatically embed the object(s) of the related model based on the named relation (just like if you added it in your query -- which as discussed, is not possible, or at least not easy, in this case).

One caveat: since `Role` and `RoleMapping` are built-in models and are surely marked as non-public, I am not actually sure whether you can include them directly (but for a different reason than above).  I haven't worked enough with ACLs (yet), but presumably there's more complexity around access controls especially in related models.

So, whereas my example code above explain the **mechanics** of doing the `include` here, the policy concern may slow you down (I'd be curious to know if they do).

That said, however, I guess you could add a derived model (from `RoleMapping`) that you make public (just like you did for user), and use it instead everywhere (including in the relation to/from `user`) -- hopefully that's clear (let me know if not).

In conclusion: If you add a **`default scope`** to your derived `user` model, to do the `include` for you, the AngularJS service wrapper (built by `lb-ng`) will be none the wiser (the `include` all happens on the backend):

```
$scope.loginResult = User.login($scope.credentials,
  function wasSuccessfulAuth(authResponse) {
    console.log('Related models are here: ', authResponse.roles,
                authResponse.user);
    ...
```

In other words, the resulting model will contain an array, `.roles[]`, containing the related roles to this user (based on your relation definition), and `.user` with the entire `user` model right there!

This latter point is unclear but I'm confident in that, because I did exactly the above but with a different related model that I know works.  And to my surprise, `user` was included as well, since that's explicitly requested by the LoopBack `$resource` wrapper (the one created by `lb-ng`).  So, in fact, you don't have do a separate query to get the `user` -- it's already there! There's no API that I see when using the `$service` wrapper, to get at that built-in `include` and change it; I guess that's what was posted in a comment above.

Hope this is helpful.

Steve